# Could not call class constructor

Tags: php, database, pdo, constructor, namespaces

I've been busy trying to create my own framework (to become more experienced in this area), and stumbled on an error I couldn't fix by searching google... wow...

I want to get data from a database, placed in an object / class. I've done it before, in a different way I learned at school, but I wanted to tweak it and make it more dynamic so I could use it in my framework.

The problem I stumbled on is the following:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: could not call class constructor on line 96
```

This is the function in my database class:

```
public function getObject($query, $classRootPath)
{
    try {
        //Check if slashes are double already and make them if not
        if(!strpos($classRootPath, "\\\\")) {
            $classRootPath = str_replace("\\","\\\\",$classRootPath);
        }

        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Campers\\Camper"); // I want this path to be $classRootPath once it is working with this dummy data
        return $statement->fetchAll();

        // return $this->pdo->query($query)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Campers\\Camper");

    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \Exception("DB receive object failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

This function is nested in `Database` and the class is called `Database` / `Database.php`

The following class is nested in `Campers` and is called `Camper.php`

```
class Camper {
    public $ID, $date, $camperID;

    public function __construct($ID, $date, $camperID)
    {
        $this->ID = $ID;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->camperID = $camperID;
    }
}
```

The only reason I can think of this is not working, is that the call `"Campers\\Camper"` is calling on top of `Database`, but I don't know how to escape that. I tried with `..\` but I got errors back, and this is the closest I can get. Here it can find the class though, but it can't find the constructor of `Camper`...

I've tested if my db class / connection works, so that's not the fault.

The structure of my table matches my `Campers` class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PSR-4 spec](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/):

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

You likely can't instantiate that `Camper` class as-is anyway. PSR-4 expects your filename to match the class. It should be located in `framework/Campers/Camper.php`.

Comment: Okay, so if I (the other way around) would take away framework from the namespace (which actually is a bit of overuse), it should work?

Trying right now

EDIT: Tried, still the same error :\

Comment: Your original issue was the naming conflict between your class and the file it was contained within. If you're still getting the same error, make sure you're passing the fully qualified classname into the `->execute(...)` call. If you're still having problems, providing a clearer picture of your directory structure and the `psr4` section of your `composer.json` will be helpful.

Comment: I also recommend against updating your original question with fixes you get from answers. Append updates to your question instead to make the process you went through to fix your issue clear.

Answer (score 0):

This error implies more than been unable to call the constructor, it is also used to indicate than an error occurred while calling it.

In my case, an Exception was been thrown inside de constructor. If you don't print/log the stacktrace, you could easily miss it.

Enjoy!
:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in at least 3 cases.

Case 1: You select something from the database that can contain a NULL value.

```
SELECT name FROM tableX;
```

In that case I do the select in that way:

```
SELECT IFNULL(name,'') AS name FROM tableX;
```

where name is a field in your class.

Case 2: You select something that is not a field in your class

```
class Example {
  public string $name = '';
}
```

Then the following query will fail as id is not declared in your class

```
SELECT id, name FROM tableX;
```

case3:

your field in the class isn't initialised

```
class Example {
  public string $name;
}

SELECT name FROM tableX;
```

can be solved by either initialise the field

```
class Example {
  public string $name = '';
}
```

or using a constructor to declare it

BR